# не работает должным образом кастомный курсор

Tags: css

На одном из видео нашел очень простую реализацию кастомного курсора с помощью css + js.

css:

```css
.cursor {
  position: fixed;
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: var(--black);
  transition: 0.1s;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  pointer-events: none;
  z-index: 200000;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

a:hover~.cursor {
  transform: scale(6);
  -moz-transform: scale(6);
}
```

js:

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  cursor.style.left = e.clientX + 'px';
  cursor.style.top = e.clientY + 'px';
})
```

Реализация должна состоять в следующем: мы имеем курсор (точку) черного цвета с шириной и высотой по 15 px. При наведении на ссылки, курсор должен изменять свой масштаб (transform: scale(6)). И т.к. ссылки на сайте черного цвета, при наведении курсора на ссылку, цвет ссылки должен стать белым с помощью свойства mix-blend-mode: difference. Но mix-blend-mode не срабатывает вообще (также пробовал с префиксами).

Если вместо тэга a поставить здесь a:hover ~ .cursor, например, тэг header, то transform:scale() срабатывает. Но mix-blend-mode: difference не меняет цвет ссылки на белый.

Как сделать так, чтобы transform: scale() срабатывал именно на ссылки при наведении? И как правильно реализовать изменение цвета ссылки, когда курсор будет наведен на нее (возможно есть варианты, подобные mix-blend-mode)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Как задействовать все ссылки на странице?

- Следующее правило (селектор `~` - указывает на **любой соседний нижележащий** элемент с классом *cursor*):

  ```css
  a:hover~.cursor {
    transform: scale(6);
    -moz-transform: scale(6);
  }
  ```

  требует, чтобы блок `.cursor` имел общий родительский элемент со ссылкой (ссылками) и, при этом, стоял после ссылки (ссылок). Таким образом, блоки `.cursor` должны стоять везде, где есть ссылки. Такой подход неправильный, затратный и не обладает какой бы то ни было гибкостью. Хотя, если эффект нужен не по всей странице, а в пределах, например, блока навигации, то ваш вариант может сработать.

Решение здесь простое - задействовать JS, для отслеживания курсора на ссылках и на элементах внутри них.

#### Почему не работают свойства смешивания?

- Часто, при использовании фильтров и свойств смешивания (`mix-blend-mode` и `background-blend-mode`), забывают про то, что большинство элементов имеют значение  фонового цвета по умолчанию `none` или `transparent`. То же справедливо для тегов `<html>` и `<body>`. Из-за этого некоторые эффекты не работают должным образом - как можно смешивать цвет с "ничем" или с абсолютной прозрачностью? Поэтому рекомендуется явно задавать цвет.
- Также желательно указывать размеры (высоту) `<html>` и `<body>` - во многих источниках оговаривается, что несоблюдение этого условия может сказаться на эффектах смешивания (хотя прямой ссылки на баг я не нашёл).

---

Думаю, что код ниже понятен без дополнительных комментариев:

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector('.cursor');

document.addEventListener('mousemove', (ev) => {
  cursor.style.left = `${ev.pageX}px`;
  cursor.style.top = `${ev.pageY}px`;
});
document.addEventListener('mouseover', (ev) => {
  let target = ev.target.closest('a');
  cursor.classList.toggle('hover', target);
});
```

```css
html {
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #fff;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #fff;
  cursor: none;
}

.cursor {
  position: absolute;
  height: 15px; width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
  background-color: #fff;
  pointer-events: none;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}
.cursor.hover { transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(6); }

a { color: black; /* cursor: none; */ }
```

```html
<nav>
  <a href="#">Первый</a>
  <a href="#"><i>Второй</i></a>
  <a href="#"><b>Третий</b></a>
</nav>
<hr>
<ul>
  <li><a href="#">Четвёртый</a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><em>Пятый</em></a></li>
  <li><a href="#"><strong>Шестой</strong></a></li>
</ul>
<h1><a href="#"><span>Седьмой</span></a></h1>

<div class="cursor"></div>
```

Comment: Спасибо за твой ответ. Для меня было очень важно услышать подробные объяснения, как это сделал ты. За это отдельно благодарю. Я протестировал твой код в моем проекте. Все заработало. Но есть одно но. Курсор отрабатывает как надо на главном экране. Но как только я скролю вниз (хотя бы на 50-100px), то курсор ниже не двигается. Он как будто остается там, на главном экране. Не подскажешь, почему так?

Comment: @PavelS: рад был помочь. По поводу скролла - каюсь, мой недосмотр - нужно `pageX/Y` вместо `clientX/Y`. Поправил.

Comment: Благодарю! Теперь все работает в лучшем виде!